# AngularJS changes URLs to "unsafe:" in extension page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use Angular with a list of apps, and each one is a link to see an app in more detail (`apps/app.id`):

```
<a id="{{app.id}}" href="apps/{{app.id}}" >{{app.name}}</a>
```

Every time I click on one of these links, Chrome shows the URL as

```
unsafe:chrome-extension://kpbipnfncdpgejhmdneaagc.../apps/app.id
```

Where does the `unsafe:` come from?

Comment: Keep in mind that you should use `ng-href` in this case rather than just `href`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: I just use a controller method `function gotoURL(url) {
   $window.location.href = url;
  }`

Answer (score 370, accepted):

You need to explicitly add URL protocols to Angular's whitelist using a regular expression. Only `http`, `https`, `ftp` and `mailto` are enabled by default. Angular will prefix a non-whitelisted URL with `unsafe:` when using a protocol such as `chrome-extension:`.

A good place to whitelist the `chrome-extension:` protocol would be in your module's config block:

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
        // Angular before v1.2 uses $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(...)
    }
]);
```

The same procedure also applies when you need to use protocols such as `file:` and `tel:`.

Please see the AngularJS [$compileProvider API documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compileProvider) for more info.

Comment: In Angular 1.2 the method name became `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist`

Comment: Default imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist Angular 1.2-rc2 is `/^\s*(https?|ftp|file):|data:image\//`, to access the local filesystem for a chrome packaged app `|filesystem:chrome-extension:` should be added to the end of the regex.

Comment: Note that in Angular 1.2, there are actually two methods -- One for links (aHrefSanitizationWhitelist) and one for images (imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist). This had me stuck for a while.

Comment: For a Chrome Packaged App you'll need to add `|blob:chrome-extension:` to the end.

Comment: Note that this does not work for images, for images look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22798336/1277693

Comment: Note the file protocol is different from the blob protocol:     `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|blob|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);`

Comment: I think the author forgot to escape the `-` character in `chrome-extension`. The regexp should be something like /^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome\-extension):/

Comment: @Vladius, afaik the `-` char would only need escaping if it were to appear within a character set `[]`, in which case an unescaped `-` would represent a range. The unescaped `-` should be fine in this scenario.

Answer (score 58):

In case anyone has this problem with images, as well:

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);
}]);
```

Comment: I tried using the regular expression for white listing the image screen shots i am capturing with html2canvas , now there is no error that says unsafe:data; but the image is not getting captured. Any idea what regular expression i shall use ? I am capturing a image/png as base64 url. Now the html looks like : <img ng-src="data:," class="img-responsive" src="data:,"> instead of the actual base64 url

Answer (score 6):

If you just need for mail, tel and sms use this:

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|sms|tel):/);
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="{{applicant.resume}}" download> download resume</a>


var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
         $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);

        }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome require its extensions to cooperate with `Content Security Policy (CSP)`.

You need to modify your extension to fulfill the requirements of `CSP`.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP

Also, angularJS has `ngCsp` directive which you need to use.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCsp

Comment: I already have the ngCsp directive for that page '<html ng-app="myApp" ng-csp>'.
This is the CSP from my manifest:
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",`

Do I need to change the csp in the manifest?

Answer (score 2):

For `Angular 2+` you can use `DomSanitizer`'s `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` method.

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

class ExampleComponent {
    sanitizedURL : SafeResourceUrl;

    constructor(
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
        this.sanitizedURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you provide a more elaborated example for the same.

Comment: Hi @JayeshChoudhary,
Can you please let me know what you're specifically looking for and I might be able to help you better.