# unsafe link in angular

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, in the following scenario, Firefox puts `unsafe:` in front of urls that are generated in the following fashion. It then display an error-page saying "The address wasn't understood". This is a file request on my local PC.

Link:

```
<li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <a href="{{ fruit.link }}">{{ fruit.title }}</a>
</li>
```

Array:

```
$scope.fruits = [
    {   "title"     :   "Orange",
        "link"      :   "fruits_orange.html"  }
];
```

Comment: try using `ng-href`..see docs

Answer (score 46):

You are seeing side-effect of this commit:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9532234bf1c408af9a6fd2c4743fdb585b920531 that aims at addressing some security hazards.

This commit introduced a non-backward compatible change for urls starting with `file://` (it was subsequently relaxed in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7b236b29aa3a6f6dfe722815e0a2667d9b7f0899

I assume that you are using one of 1.0.5 or 1.1.3 AngularJS versions. If so you can re-enable support for the `file://` URLs by configuring `$compileProvider` like so:

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function ($compileProvider) {

  $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file):/);

});
```

Or in Angular 1.2.8 and above:

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function ($compileProvider) {

  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file):/);

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do I need to put this code? If I just put it into my controller (and add $compileProvider to the argument list), it says `Error: Unknown provider: $compileProviderProvider`. 

I am using 1.0.5 (latest from google developers).

Comment: Btw, a quick fix is just using 1.0.4.

Comment: @Ben you need to put this code in your module's configuration block as noted in my response (and the source code that goes with it). You can read about modules here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module And of course reverting to 1.0.4 will make issue go away as only 1.0.5 and 1.1.3 are affected.

Comment: As of Angular 1.2.8, please use `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` for `ng-href`, and other specialized functions for `src` and the like.

Comment: I could not get your answer to work, and until I found that the whitelist you provided did not satisfy the "#" character: from this GitHub issue: (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2901#issuecomment-24157693) came this whitelist regex: `(/^\s*((https?|ftp|mailto|file|chrome-extension|tel):)|#/)`

Answer (score 5):

Add a white list to your controller.

For Angular.js 1.2:

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|tel):/);
}]);
```

For Angular 1.1.x and 1.0.x, use `urlSanitizationWhitelist`. 
See [reference](http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/09/avoid-angularjs-from-adding-unsafe-tag.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
    angular.module('somemodule').config(['$compileProvider' , function ($compileProvider)
    {
          $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto):/);
    }]);
```

Comment: For Angular 1.2+ I used a similar solution from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `angular 1.4.0` and the following format worked:

```
ng-href="http://{{baseURLHref}}{{baseURLPort}}/routingPathName"
```

Adding `http://` in the beginning of `ng-href` helped in getting rid of the `unsafe` appended by `ng-Sanitize`

- If you're on `https`, then it shouldn't be a problem to hard code everything.
- But if you've a system that has to work on both environments, you might want to use a protocol detection from `location.protocol`

I'm setting the variables in `$rootScope` (they help with issues with proxy servers that consume css from my site)

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.baseURLHref = '';
    $rootScope.baseURLPort = '';
    if($location.host() != 'localhost'){
      $rootScope.baseURLHref = $location.host();
      $rootScope.baseURLPort = ':' + $location.port();
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{applicant.resume}}" download> download resume</a>


var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
         $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);

        }]);
```