# filter service changes from Angularjs 1.0.3 to 1.0.7

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

With this example: http://jsfiddle.net/lesouthern/y3pXn/
for this filter:

```
.filter('telanchor',function() {
    return function(s) {
        var rString = '';
        if(typeof s !== 'undefined' && angular.isString(s)) {
            rString = 'tel:+' + s.replace(/\D/g,'');
        }
        return rString;
    }
})
```

It filters correctly to this string in Angular 1.0.3:

```
    <a href="tel:+5103381927">Tel Number</a>
```

In 1.0.7 it generates to:

```
    <a href="unsafe:tel:+5103381927">Tel Number</a>
```

How do I not generate this 'unsafe' string?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular seems to be recognizing your href as unsafe.
Try something like this in your configuration block:

```
angular.module('module').config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider)
{
      $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
      /* The regular expression will match your "unsafe"
        link format and add it to the whitelist */
}]);
```

Here's a more detailed explanation: [unsafe link in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637622/1266600)