# angularjs unsafe ng-href using javascript: void(0);

Tags: angularjs

I have a similar question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637133/unsafe-link-in-angular).

But adding "javascript" what was proposed in the answer didn't resolve my problem:

```
$compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|javascript):/);
```

My code looks something like:

```
<a ng-href="{{var1 ? '/home' : 'javascript: void(0);'}}" ng-bind="var2"></a>
```

But in the url, it produces an `unsafe:javascript: void(0);`

Comment: Is this problem associated with a specific browser and what version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Maybe consider picking the other answer as the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be some error in your code then. You can see it working just fine in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fEujaU

Answer (score 41):

I assume you use the latest version of AngularJS.  The method name has been changed since that SO answer.

```
myapp.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|javascript):/);
});
```

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ht0tbH?p=preview).