# AngularJS: <a> tag not working on url's created by $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a temp url for a blob using:

```
var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Then I use `$sce` to make angular trust the url:

```
$scope.contentStream = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
```

Then I use `contentStream` on the anchor tag:

```
<a href="{{contentStream}}" download="Name Of File">Download File</a>
```

All this works fine, the only problem is once `contentStream` is rendered in the `a` tag, the link looks like `unsafe:blob:http%3A//192.168.88.110%3A8989/0e62a86e-4cb6-4603-8895-3f238ea8c55c` and when I click on the link, it does not work. I realised `unsafe:` causes problem, then I take the same link put it on a new tab without `unsafe:` the pdf file gets rendered.

**My question is:**

How do I remove `unsafe:` before `contentStream` is rendered by the browser and still make it safe for angular to trust the url?

Comment: I think this issue was addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15637622/650301) I also made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLtxlA7xXqLn6v8qNm1C?p=preview) that reproduces your issue.