# angularjs unsafe twitter link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

Here's my twitter link in angular:

```
a.preventDefault(href='javascript:window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer={{url}}&url={{url}}", "_blank", "width=400,height=500");void(0);') Twitter
```

The result is

```
<a href="unsafe:javascript:window.open(&quot;https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=&amp;url=&quot;, &quot;_blank&quot;, &quot;width=400,height=500&quot;);void(0);" class="preventDefault">Twitter</a>
```

What's with the unsafe stuff? It doesn't work. How do I fix it thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637133/unsafe-link-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unsafe tag is added by windows. You need to make the html safe or else you need to whitelist these urls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't much about the "safelink", but I think using the wrapper object [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24window) instead of the raw object window is better. Because may be angular does many things by default when using the wrapper object