# using ng-href with javascript in anchor tag (bookmarklet)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I am trying to create a bookmarklet on an anchor tag using angularjs.

When the script is static, there is no need to use angularjs code.
but when it is dynamic, both `href` and `ng-href` are appending `'unsafe'` to the JavaScript.

tried DOM manipulation and it worked perfectly.

Instead of scriptlet, if i am using a URL, both `href` and `ng-href` are working properly

http://plnkr.co/edit/0l4AbOLbCPhE5c9OLWD2?p=preview

Comment: This might give you a clue about your issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637133/unsafe-link-in-angular

Comment: Thanks @karthik. It worked after using
`$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(javascript):/);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `href` and the below code, but it did have the `unsafe:javascript` in front of the JavaScript function.

```
angular.module("app").config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(javascript‌​):/);
}]);
```