# MEAN stack angular html <img> tag inject not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

im new to angular so im trying something new to get used to it.

I use socket.io to get a list of images [car1...car5] and i want to dynamically inject them to the view.

in my html i have a  that looks like this:

```
<div id="section" ng-bind-html="HTML">
    </div>
```

and in my core.js angular script i have:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.factory('socket', function () {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  return socket;
});

app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, socket)
{
    socket.emit('images', {}); //send for a list of images
    socket.on('returnImages', function(data)
    {
        for(var i =1;i<=data.list.length;i++) 
        {
            $scope.HTML = '<img style="left:'+(i*50)+'px;" src="/images/'+data.list[i]+'"/>';
        }
        $scope.$digest();
    });
});
```

but this throws an error:

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$sce/unsafe etc
```

im following the docs so im not sure whats wrong and i tried including the angular-sanitize but I cant find the cdn link i keep getting a 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make html trusted

First inject `$sce` service in your controller

Like this

```
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, socket,$sce)
{

}
```

Then make your html trusted

```
$scope.HTML = $sce.trustAsHtml('<img style="left:'+(i*50)+'px;" src="/images/'+data.list[i]+'"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the request domain to white list

check this: [unsafe link in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637133/unsafe-link-in-angular)