# details on mock $compileProvider in AngularJS unit tests

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm configuring `$compileProvider` in my Angular app so I can insert telephone links into my HTML, as detailed in [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/YiP02I1wkNU/discussion):

```
app.config ['$compileProvider', ($compileProvider) ->
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist /^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/
]
```

This works fine.

However, now my unit tests (in Karma) die with `TypeError: Object #<$CompileProvider> has no method 'urlSanitizationWhitelist'`. I think that means the mock `$compileProvider` is different than the regular one. So how can I get my unit tests to run again?

Comment: The trivial answer is to check whether the call will work before I make it, a one-character change in CoffeeScript: `$compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist? /^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/` . But I'm looking for an answer clarifying the mock `$compileProvider`.

Comment: You might want to set @Eric Bowers's answer as "fixed my question"?

Answer (score 4):

Since Angular 1.2 the method has been changed to $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist()

This answer came from here: [Angular changes urls to "unsafe:" in extension page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page)