# generate skype links with angular

Tags: angularjs, skype

I am trying to generate skype links in a web page using Angular. If I hard-code the link with the skype username (e.g. `<a href="skype:some_username?chat&topic=fubar">...`) the link operates as expected and opens a dialog asking me what to do with external protocols.

But if I generate the link using `skype:{{skype.user}}` the link doesn't work and the status-bar reads `unsafe: skype:some_username?chat&topic=fubar`

- Mac OSX 10.8.4
- Chrome 28.0.1500.71

[**Plunked Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ecR79yAZrceAZqZ1CW5?p=preview)

I've checked chrome in groups, and skype support blog, also googled. I get lots of hits for links not working from within skype, but nothing about generated skype links failing.

This is a [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page)

[**Plunked Solution Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o2qiaLGOIO2tt07dQBC9?p=preview)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page)

Comment: that did the trick... sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code:**

```
var app = angular.module("yourApp", []);

app.config(['$compileProvider',function($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|skype):/);
    }
]);
```

As well you can edit protocol list by using `'|'` in `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
.config( ['$compileProvider',function( $compileProvider )
  {

  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|skype):/);

  }]);
```