# How to do navigation in a chrome packaged app using angular.js?

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs, navigation, google-chrome-app

I'm experimenting with [chrome packaged apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html), my first screen has a list of items, when i click on an item, a detail page should be visible.

I a normal web app you just do:

```
<a href="#/detail/{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a>
```

But in a packaged app i get the following error:

> Can't open same-window link to
>   "unsafe:chrome-extension://fsdjiojkljkljdfijkjkijkjkjijikf/index.html#/detail/blablabla";
>   try target="_blank".

So how do i do some kind of navigation in a chrome packaged app?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to make this work by following answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page

Comment: @romario333 that's the best answer by itself !!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @romario333, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769779/122441 :

You need to explicitly add URL protocols to Angular's whitelist using a regular expression. Only `http`, `https`, `ftp` and `mailto` are enabled by default. Angular will prefix a non-whitelisted URL with `unsafe:` when using a protocol such as `chrome-extension:`.

A good place to whitelist the `chrome-extension:` protocol would be in your module's config block:

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
        // Angular before v1.2 uses $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(...)
    }
]);
```

The same procedure also applies when you need to use protocols such as `file:` and `tel:`.

Please see the AngularJS [$compileProvider API documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compileProvider) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Navigation in chrome packaged apps is disabled for aesthetic UI reasons (page navigations don't "feel" like an app). See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated.html.

Here are some alternatives to doing navigation:

-Open a new app window

-Manipulate the DOM of the current window

-Use an iframe, sandboxed iframe, or webview tag. See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html for some documentation.

-Use html fragment identifiers/links (I believe these still work even though navigation doesn't, but am not positive)

Comment: Actually, it looks like URL fragments via `window.location.hash` doesn't work consistently in packaged apps: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57162