# Android unsafe:tel: with phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I coded an application with phonegap.

I have a phone numbers list that I receive from a server.
when an item from a list is clicked the controller trigers this function:

```
$scope.call = function(number){
        document.location.href = 'tel:' + number;
    }
```

on an iPhone it's ok, but on an Android I get:

```
unsafe:tel:+97235726333
```

why? Is it a utf-8 encoded problem?

Comment: Are you by any chance data binding `tel:` href attributes with Angular? Angular uses a whitelist for protocols, and will add `unsafe:` before any URL using a protocol that uses a protocol that's not in the whitelist. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page

Comment: i tried add the code that displayed there and get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<$CompileProvider> has no method 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' from MyApp

Comment: ok, i change thr function to urlSanitizationWhitelist
i will check that thank you

Answer (score 0):

some systems dont take the + in to considerations, i know i have had some issues with that in the past with older projects. one thing you could do is replace the + with 00 two zero's is the same as a plus, which then becomes a full integer without the + which might the the issue with the internal parser.

```
$scope.call = function(number){
   document.location.href = 'tel:' + number.replace("+","00");
}
```