# $sce.trustAsUrl doesn't seem to work for base64 image links

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use `$sce.trustAsUrl`, but it doesn't seem to work. My HTML looks like,

```
<a ng-href="{{img_src}}" target="_blank">the image</a>
```

and the Angular JS in question is like this,

```
$scope.img_src = $sce.trustAsUrl("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...");
```

I know I can try `$sce.trustAsHtml`, but this seems like a hack. Am I doing something wrong, or is Angular just buggy?

Full example (JS fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/njjkg8vr/

Comment: This would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks! full example: http://jsfiddle.net/8u0n632f/