# ui-sref: how to generate link without origin in chrome app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui-router, google-chrome-app

I create packaged chrome application with AngularJS and ui-router. Application has this config to work with url:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider,   $routerProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routerProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        controller: 'Login',
        templateUrl: "/part/login/index.html"
    });

    $stateProvider.state('cabinet', {
        templateUrl: '/part/cabinet/index.html',
        abstract: true
    });

    $stateProvider.state('cabinet.cars', {
        url: '/cars',
        templateUrl: '/part/cars/cars.html',
        controller: 'CarsList'
    });

    $stateProvider.state("cabinet.cars.car", {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: '/part/cars/car.html',
        controller: function() {console.log('ok');}
    });

}]);
```

When I try to create link with:

```
<a ui-sref="cabinet.cars.car({id: 1})">Link</a>
```

Then I get this link:

```
<a ui-sref="cabinet.cars.car({id: 1})" href="unsafe:chrome-extension://jnjgkohadplkakigldhhojdfdihgdigf/#/cars/1">Link</a>
```

As you can see, link contains this part:

```
unsafe:chrome-extension://jnjgkohadplkakigldhhojdfdihgdigf
```

And it not work. When I click on it, nothing to do.

Tell me please, how I can create link without origin part of url?

Thank you.

### Answer

I am find this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769779/2114208

It help me to solve problem.

Comment: Deleted my answer; it did not address the problem, sorry.

Comment: @Xan, that's all right

Comment: What does the [`href()` method](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options) of the state produce?

Comment: @Xan, than you for help. I am find reason of my problem and update question.