# ng-href directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in AngularJS and I'm having some issues using the ng-href.

I have an array containing dictionaries.

`$scope.options = [{title: 'option1', path:'optionPage'}, ... ];`

In the HTML code, I make use of `ng-repeat` within a `<table></table>` to display options; each row being a link. Below is the code.

```
<table class="table">
     <tr ng-repeat="option in options">
        <td><a href="#optionPage">{{option.title}}</a></td> <!-- This works -->
        <td><a ng-href="#{{option.path}}">{{option.title}}</a></td> <!-- This does not work!! -->
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Using the `a href` and directly providing the link works. (I am making use of the $route), but `ng-href` doesn't work. Could somebody please point out the issue here.

Comment: what is the value of option.path

Comment: It will be optionPage. You can see that in the options list.

Comment: oops I missed it, so when you mouse over the links,in browser bottom-left corner url will be highlighted, are both links identical when you mouse over them

Comment: Actly Im working on a chrome extension, so that link is not visible like you mentioned. Extension appears as a popup.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided in the below link helped me solve my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769779/1029360

The `chrome-extension:` protocol needs to be whitelisted before use.