# Angular.js aHrefSanitizationWhitelist not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chromium-embedded

I'm experimenting a little bit with the [basic Angular.js tutorial](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-12/app/#/phones), but I'm having trouble trying to set up the url-schema's whitelist.

Basically I'm trying to add a custom scheme (*cust-scheme*) to the whitelist of angular, in order to avoid it from prefixing urls with `unsafe:`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769779/2304450) StackOverflow's answer, I just need to add `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|cust-scheme):/);`
to the config parameters of the app.

I tried the following:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'phonecatAnimations',

  'phonecatControllers',
  'phonecatFilters',
  'phonecatServices'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }],
  ['$compileProvider',
  function( $compileProvider ) {   
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|cust-scheme):/);
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|cust-scheme):/);
  }
]);
```

but it doesn't work. The routing is fine but the *cust-scheme* schema is not whitelisted.
Is there anything I'm missing? Perhaps I'm doing the multiple configurations thing wrong?

I also tried the following:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'phonecatAnimations',

  'phonecatControllers',
  'phonecatFilters',
  'phonecatServices'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]
);

phonecatApp.config(function( $compileProvider ) {   
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|cust-scheme):/);
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|cust-scheme):/);
  }
);
```

In this second case, the schema was whitelisted but the routing didn't work anymore.

Any help is appreciated!

Yours sincerly,
an Angular.js newbie :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are just a bit off syntactically, so lets try to "merge" these two code snippets together. Hopefully this code is self describing and you can see that we are injecting `$routeProvider` and `$compileProvider` together in a min-safe and verbose way to call our app `.config` at once

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', function($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);

    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
}]);
```

Comment: Almost there! I can now see images, but routing is still messed up. Clicking on a phone (I'm referring to the original example linked in the question) the app reloads the same phone list view...

Comment: @GavinoGrifoni Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I already have `/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|filesystem|filesystem:chrome-extension|blob:chrome-extension|cust-scheme):/` as regex, doesn't help

Comment: Is the `href` on your phones in the following format? `<a href="#/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi">`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68928/discussion-between-sal-niro-and-gavinogrifoni).

Comment: I'm accepting this as the correct answer. The other problems (highlighted here in the comments) such as the routing were caused by Chromium Embedded Framework, so indeed this is the solution to the original problem.