# Why ng-href behaving weird while parsing geo string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, geo, angularjs-ng-href

I've multiple geo string like `geo:0,0q=1+a+bc`, and I'm gonna assign this to `ng-href` of the anchor tag. Like below I'm doing it.

**HTML**

```
<a ng-href="{{geoString}}">Location</a> </br>
```

Above tag is rendering fine on HTML but adding `unsafe:` string `geo:0,0q=1+a+bc` inside `href` attribute

**Rendered HTML**

```
<a ng-href="geo:0,0q=12345+jefferson+st" href="unsafe:geo:0,0q=12345+jefferson+st">Location</a>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MjrZlz85FaFmpqbwy8UD?p=preview) with demonstrating issue.

I don't want `unsafe:` inside `href`, Any idea why it is pre-appending  `unsafe:` before `geoString` & How do i remove it?

Comment: I believe this will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use aHrefSanitizationWhitelist([regexp]);

regex should match the url of your's So in your case it should be like

```
 $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(geo):/);
```

regEx:- starting with geo followed by ' : '

Please see [$compileProvider Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider) for more info.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJBXRpy09CZquvLzJA4B?p=preview)

Comment: Bingo for the doc link :-)