# Webview restrictions for dynamic content injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webview, windows-runtime

I am developing winrt 8.1 app with webview component.
I am using angular on the webview content.
I have a problem with setting the image (html control) source as angular binding...The source is injected by angular controller and I get this prefix in the inage src:
Prefix:
"unsafe:ms-local-stream://01010101-0101-0101-0101-0101010101212_64656d6f32"
Full path:
unsafe:ms-local-stream://01010101-0101-0101-0101-0101010101212_64656d6f32/test.png.
If I am changing the path to the "test.png" manually (removing the "unsafe" prefix), with the DOM Explorer - then the image appears. But when it's injected I get this prefix that shows no image since the path is not found on the LocalFolder.
how can I disable this behavior?

The image source is injected by angular.

If the source is static : 
 
It works, but as the same src replaced with injection , it gets this prefix...
Usually webview is very restricted with dynamic content, i had problems with dynamic html injection when I used Angular on WinJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `$compileProvider` which do compilation of html, you need tell the `$compileProvider` that you should allow `ms-local-stream://` while adding in `src` tag that can be done inside `$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist` method. If you don't specified the sanitization whitelist then angular will add `unsafe:` prefix in the value. This setting you could add in config of you app.

**Markup**

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}" alt="Title"/>
```

**Code**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', 
  function($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
    //this is for anchor href
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ms-local-stream):/); 
    //this is for img src
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ms-local-stream):/); 
}]);
```

Refer same [**SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28913139/2435473).

Comment: I set ng-src and I get the same result, I think that the problem is on the webview side and not in my angular.

Comment: @paveldurov did you added suggested code in you app config?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was rushing... I added the code and now my application is crushing, so I'll try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, adding ms-local-stream to $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist  definitely helped. But still the source that images are binded to, cannot be determined by webview as localstream or storageFile. So, right now, i am catching the "navigation" in my IUriToStreamResolver and I trimm the unsafe prefix....

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) in your `img` tag rather than `src` since you are injection the value.

In other words rather than

```
<img src="{{hash}}" /> <!-- this won't work as the browser will try to fetch the literal value {{hash}} -->
```

Try this instead

```
<img ng-src="{{hash}}" /> <!-- this will interpolate {{hash}} before fetching the image -->
```

(Hard to say without seeing your code though...)