# Whatsapp Sharing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, anchor, href, whatsapp

Simple as it should be, it won't work as this code can't detect AngularJS codes.

```
    <a href="whatsapp://send?text={{challenge.challenge_title}}" 
            data-action="{{FullURL}}">Whatsapp</a>
```

Do i need a directive for this? If yes, what is it? 
Someone with experience in AngularJS, kindly help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to sanitize anchor `href` inside your `config` phase of angular, that will allow your href with `whatsapp` prefix.

**Code**

```
app.config(function($compileProvider){
   //other configuration code here
   $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(whatsapp):/);
})
```

Look this [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913139/why-ng-href-behaving-weird-while-parsing-geo-string) for details.

Comment: @user3362364 could you look at mine answer?

Comment: Sorry about this. I tested and it didn't work. Was expecting more people to comment and time went by. I added your code in app.js and ended it with a semi-colon but it didn't work with the following error (i'm a newbie): ReferenceError: $compileProvider is not defined. PS: My angularJS guy is on leave for another ~10 days

Comment: Please note that it works perfectly if i directly add link such as http://domain.com/ instead of the {{FullURL}}

Comment: @user3362364 Do try updated..add `$compileProvider` in config function

Comment: @user3362364 Glad to hear that..Thanks :)

Comment: @Pankhaj Parkar This adds "unsafe" on all my ui-sref. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3362364 did you added this config block in your app? After adding this you would not get `unsafe:` thing prefix with href ..I think you should use `ng-href` for the different domain `URL`

Comment: I added this in app.js but still getting the error. I have to define state and so use ui-sref. Any way out?

Comment: could you update you question with more details please?

Answer (score 0):

I faced an issue of unsafe URL after using $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(whatsapp):/); when i read the angular docs it says:

aHrefSanitizationWhitelist([regexp]);
Retrieves or overrides the default regular expression that is used for whitelisting of safe urls during a[href] sanitization.
The sanitization is a security measure aimed at preventing XSS attacks via html links.
Any url about to be assigned to a[href] via data-binding is first normalized and turned into an absolute url. Afterwards, the url is matched against the aHrefSanitizationWhitelist regular expression. If a match is found, the original url is written into the dom. Otherwise, the absolute url is prefixed with 'unsafe:' string and only then is it written into the DOM.
"If a match is found, the original url is written into the dom. Otherwise, the absolute url is prefixed with 'unsafe:' string and only then is it written into the DOM."
So for all other urls other than whatsapp, the match will not be found
and it will be marked as unsafe

The another is way to make a directive

```js
angular.module('shareLink')
  .directive('whatsApp', function (){
    return{
        link: function (scope, elem, $attr){
            elem.on('click', function (){
                var text = $attr.text;
                var url = $attr.whatsApp;
                var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
                var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
                window.location.href = whatsapp_url;

            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<a class="sharelink whatsapp"  data-action="share/whatsapp/share" data-text="you can add title or any text here" whats-app="{{url}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-whatsapp "></i> WHATSAPP
                    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text={{Your desired Text}}" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" class="share-btn whatsapp" >Share on Whatsapp</a>
```

This is the most easiest process...

Cheers.