# whatsapp sharing button- share url is incorrect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, whatsapp

I am adding share button in my website, and my share URL has some parameters. However, on phone extra parameters in the URL are ignored.

my button :

```
<a class='whatsapp-icon' href='whatsapp://send?text=https://www.exmaple.com/#/lat=10.11,long=20.11'></a>
```

When I open this link in webpage link it open fine with all parameters, but on the phone link comes as just www.exmaple.com and parameter '#/lat=10.11,long=20.11' is ignored in share window.

This is angular 1.xx webpage where share button is present.

Answer (score 1):

**LATEST WAY TO DO THIS**

```
<a *ngIf="isWhatsAppIconVisible" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=check out this link : {{shareableUrl}}" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
    <img src="assets/whatsapp.png" alt="whatsapp" /> 
</a>
```

Comment: The question was for AngularJS, not Angular

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize anchor `href`. Here you can find a solution for your problem:

[Whatsapp Sharing in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624056/whatsapp-sharing-in-angularjs)

Keep rocking!

Comment: @kumarkundan: then what's the most up to date way to achieve this?