# Firefox addon using AngularJS - "ng-src" not working

Tags: angularjs, firefox-addon

I am working on a Firefox add-on that uses AngularJS.
The issue is with 'ng-src'. It does not load the referenced image.
When I switch to 'src' the image loads fine.

Example.html and 'icon-32.png' are within same folder.

Appreciate your help in making sense of this issue.

Below are the code snippets.

Example.html

```
<html ng-app="MyAddon" ng-csp>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" dir="{{dirr}}">
        <div border="0">
            <img ng-src="{{logo}}" width="32" align="center">
            <input id="textbox" type="text"> </input>
            <button id="textboxbutton" type="button"> {{ButtonText}}</button>
        </div>

    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.ButtonText= 'Hit me!';
    $scope.dirr = 'rtl';
    $scope.logo= 'icon-32.png';
};

var MyModule = angular.module('MyAddon', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', MainController)
```

Comment: Can you make an xpi out of your addon and then upload to github and share with me. I have some angular experience and can help but need to replicate issue.

Comment: Thanks for response. I could not get the file uploaded to github. I have uploaded to: http://www.megafileupload.com/97dL/jid1-SerTv5IR3fjj3Q@jetpack-0.1.xpi

Comment: Is there any way you can get that your source code on a public repository site (maybe not github but something like github?). Im cautious of downloading files.

Comment: the link to code on git: https://github.com/nkanand/FFAddon.git. Thanks and appreciate your help

Comment: Hey nandu you inspired me to get back to using anuglar for some very easy gui's i did that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087180/custom-directive-blocked?noredirect=1#comment52071207_32087180 had an issue and got it fixed, thanks for your inspiration!! :D Its helping me get out an addon Ive been delaying for awhile due to the GUI headache, angular takes care of it all for me! Heres my github repo: https://github.com/Noitidart/MailtoWebmails/blob/master/resources/scripts/app.js#L142-L148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because angular keeps adding `unsafe:` to your image url. I think this is the solution, please try: [Angular changes urls to "unsafe:" in extension page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page)

and whitelist the `resource://` urls. without `unsafe:` it works.

I saw this from using DOM Inspector:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. I had to use imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(filesystem:resource|resource):/); . Could you tell me how you got DOM inspector options for Add-ons?

Comment: Wow thanks for that share, I thought just doing a simple `/^\s*resource:/)` would fix it, how did you figure out you had to use `filesystem:resource`? Get the [addon Element Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/) then shift+right click whatever you want to inspect. :) Can you update your github with the working code im interested to see :)

Comment: since the image was local i had to use imgSrcSanitizationWhiltelist and reference local dir. I have updated the source in github. Thanks again for your help.