# Sip not working in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, lync-2013, angularjs-ng-href

I am getting the user details from a webservice.

Everything is fine except that the javascript is adding an unsafe attribute to the email Id field.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50">
        <span class="input-label">Created By</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50" style="color:white">
        {{Idea.FirstName}}&nbsp;{{Idea.LastName}}
        <a ng-href="sip:{{Idea.EmailId}}">
            <i class="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" style="font-size:2em;color:white"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I am hovering or clicking the chat icon, a message is shown in the corner: `unsafe:sip:"EmailId"`

Comment: Can you provide the little bit more details?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-href` executes expression in context of scope. You don't need curly braces for it. So your code should be either

```
 <a ng-href="'sip:'+Idea.EmailId">
```

or

```
 <a href="sip:{{Idea.EmailId}}">
```

Comment: my question is exactly like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page                                                                                      but there they are using it for mail and i am using for IM.

Comment: Perhaps in addition to fixing binding you will also have to provide a proper sanitization regex. But the error you see clearly says binding is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Angular is having normal url as href:mailto as whitelist.
But few attribute need to loaded from the security point of view.
To start an IM through angular we need to add sip to whitelist like this

```
 var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
'$compileProvider',
function( $compileProvider )
{   
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|sip|chrome-extension):/);
}
]);
```

It will add sip to whitelist and the Lync application will start when clicked in the Icon.
This change is to be made in app.js.