# Uber api deep link from mobile web app redirects to app store

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, deep-linking, uber-api

I'm attempting to construct an `Uber` link that will direct user from mobile web app to `Uber` (app or mobile website) with prepopulated drop off and pick up data.
Following this [uber instructions](https://developer.uber.com/v1/deep-linking/#mobile-web?utm_source=thinkful&utm_campaign=party-invite-guide&utm_medium=link) for mobile web "deep linking", I got this link (appended to `<a>` element):

```
<a class="uber_butt" href="https://m.uber.com/sign-up?client_id=44oPVzp.....knAb_-0fI75&pickup_latitude=37.5&pickup_longitude=-122&pickup_nickname=My+location&dropoff_latitude=37.366209&dropoff_longitude=-121.976619&dropoff_nickname=Sibca+Square">
    <div class="icon uber_icon"></div>
</a>
```

Now when I tap on this element from `iphone`'s `safari` or `chrome` it redirects me instantly to `Uber` in `appstore` or to `uber.com` and then to `appstore`. `Uber` app is installed. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @casillas thanks for edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that's my lack of knowledge and everybody knows this already but deep links to `Uber` app (and other apps in general I suppose) actually is working from mobile browser! Atleast on latest `ios`.

Regarding link to mobile `Uber` website it was not working for me and was redirecting to app store or giving me a message that I cant access mobile page and need to install app or send a message to support (if I get rid of `sign-up` in the link), so it seems to be broken, for me atleast.

Ater all I just constructed link in the format `uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location...` - you can read details [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking) - and now on click popup appears asking if user wants to open up `Uber`. Pickup/dropoff data is passed to `Uber` app just fine.

Comment: And also, if you are using `Angular` and `ng-href` -  note that you can't use most of non standart links (like `uber:` and some more common as `sms:` if i recall this right) as angular will ecape them as unsafe. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page) will help you to fix it.