# Image marked as unsafe though compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist is used in AngularJS Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've posted it before but the solution that people were pointing did not solve it, so instead posting it again with more reknowned solution:

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension using AngularJS. In my base directive, I'm trying to show a image(a local file). Here's my manifest

```
{
    "name": "The Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "A extension for chrome browsers",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["assets/img/extension-logo.png"]
}
```

My app.js (loaded from background.js):

```
//This is adding base directive in app
var app = '<div class="my-extension"><div base></div></div>';
var wrapper = '<div ng-non-bindable>' + app + '</div>';
$('body').append(wrapper);
var myExtension = angular.module('my-extension', ['baseModule']);

myExtension.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s(https?ftp|mailto|local|data|chrome-extension):/);
}]);

window.name = '';
angular.bootstrap($('.my-extension')[0], ['my-extension']);
```

And base is:

```
var baseModule = angular.module('baseModule', []);
baseModule.directive('base', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>Hello World <img src={{logoImgURL}} /></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.logoImgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("assets/img/extension-logo.png");
        }
    }
}]);
```

Image src is getting binded with the following value:

> src="unsafe:chrome-extension://lmkgimpeoaoblkhioebjoefpkhckcojf/assets/img/extension-logo.png/"

Pardon me if the question is silly, I'm relatively super new in Extension development.

Comment: Let me delete the other one as I've edited question and solution for previous question didn't work

Comment: You should describe why it's not a duplicate in the question itself. Currently it looks like you've posted it by mistake.

Comment: If it is angularjs changes urls to “unsafe:” in extension page check this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15769779/5995040) it may help you solve the issue about the url being unsafe. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

you should add `chrome-extension` to the `img src` sanitization whitelist. same as you did for the `a href`

```
myExtension.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    // ...
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*((https?|ftp|file|blob|chrome-extension):|data:image\/)/);
}]);
```