# dataURL does not work for <a>

Tags: javascript, dom

**update**： Finally I find out the reason myself, the reason is: actually I used Angular's ng-href at the same time, which prefix a `unsafe` to the data url, I have to config the compiler service to waive that restriction like:

```
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
        // Angular before v1.2 uses $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(...)
    }
])
```

Which talks about here:
[Angular changes urls to "unsafe:" in extension page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page)

---

All:

What I want to do is read in a image as dataURL and give it to a tag as download:

```
<input type='file' name='doc' />
<a href="#" download="data">Download</a>
<script>
            var fileOBJ = $("input")[0]
                        .files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
                $("a")[0].href=e.target.result;
            }
            reader.onerror = function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileOBJ);
</script>
```

The download always failed.

But if I use a `<img>` instead of `<a>`, then the image can shown up. I do not know what is wrong with the `<a>` link

Comment: I am assuming that JS is actually called onchange of the file input?

Comment: You have to specify the `download` attribute like this `<a download='FileName' ...`!

Comment: @epascarello Yes, we can, I actually add another button to do same thing, but yes, the function gets called for sure.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I actually added that download attr in my code. Still not work

Comment: @Kuan check the working snippet down there!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the atrribute `download` on the link. Like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' name='doc' />
<a download="filename" href="#">Download</a>
<script>
  $("input").change(function() {
    var fileOBJ = $("input")[0]
      .files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $("a")[0].href = e.target.result;
      // if you want to change the download filename
      // $($("a")[0]).attr("download", "some other filename");
    }
    reader.onerror = function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileOBJ);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps describe including `change` event handler at Answer, which is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Answer (score 1):

You try to call `readAsDataURL` when there is any file selected, what throws an error. Use this method after you select some file.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
   $("a")[0].href = e.target.result;
};

reader.onerror = function(err){
   console.log(err);
};

$('#inpFile').on('change',function(){
   reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```