# how to open unsafe URL's from angular8?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to open a hyperlink `change://problem/12345678` as below from angular8 UI but it always gets redirected go `unsafe:change://problem/12345678` and doesnt open the link,I looked at [AngularJS changes URLs to "unsafe:" in extension page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angularjs-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page) and tried to use `ng-href` and running into below error,is there a simpler way to do this in angular8?

```
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="newPost.posts" multiTemplateDataRows
                class="table table-bordered table-info" style="text-align:center" *ngIf="enteredValue != ''">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay; let idx=index">
                    <th style="color: black;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
                    <span *ngIf="idx == 0">
                        <td style="color: black;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                            <a href="change://problem/{{element[column]}}">{{element[column]}} </a> </td>
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="idx == 5">
                        <table mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                            <tr *ngFor="let gerrit of element[column]">
                                <a href={{gerrit}} target="_blank">{{gerrit}} </a>
                            </tr> 
                        </table>
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="idx != 0 && idx != 5">
                        <td style="color: black;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
                    </span>
                </ng-container>
```

Error:-

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-href' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("      <span *ngIf="idx2 == 0">
                                                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let big_beast"> <a
                                                            [ERROR ->]ng-href="change://problem/{{big_beast[tempy]}}">{{big_beast[tempy]}} </a> 
                                                        </td>
                                "): ng:///AppModule/RadarInputComponent.html@109:15
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11169)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25541)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25529)
    at compiler.js:25473
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25473)
    at compiler.js:25386
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25385)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustUrl](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustUrl):

```js
class FooComponent {
  public constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public getUrl(column: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`change://problem/${column}`)
  }
}
```

and in the template:

```html
<a [attr.href]="getUrl(element[column])">{{ element[column] }}</a>
```

Comment: where should I add the class ?should I add in the corresponding `*component.ts` or someother location?

Comment: Yes, since I don't know the name and scaffold of your component class, I had to improvise with the FooComponent to visualize the usage of the DomSanitizer service.